# Error while running ./file.sh in MacOS: ss command not found

Tags: macos, bash, sh

While running `./file.sh` or `sudo sh file.sh` i get the error

```
ss command not found.
```

Also tried `chmod u+x file.sh`
I use MacOS

[Image showing the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBUsb.png)

Answer (score 2):

in your docker-bench-security.sh replace

```
req_progs='awk docker grep ss stat'
```

with

```
req_progs='awk docker grep lsof stat'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few things you should make clear:-

1. Does the sh script contain a shebang like this `#!/bin/sh`? location may vary according to your system. Try `which sh` in your terminal to find this
2. If shebang is not present then doing `./file.sh` doesn't make sense because script will not find a interpreter on its own
3. You have to do `sh file.sh` to run the script.

And why did you run `sudo sh ./file.sh`?
Do you want to run it with elevated privileges?

So I think you probably want to accomplish this:-

- `chmod 700 file.sh`(I personally prefer octal system for assigning permissions)
- `./file.sh`(If shebang is present in script on very first line)
- If not then `sh file.sh`(for this you don't even need to make the script executable)

And speaking about error you are seeing, you mistyped `sh` as `ss` ;)

Comment: nooo thats exactly my problem i type sh and i get ss its not a typo the error is literally that one

Comment: @Jose It is really weird. I have no idea then what's happening. Maybe you have used `ss` command in your script and that's why It is throwing _that_ error(because `ss` is not installed in your system)? But it also shows line no. If the error is _in_ the script itself. And also did you do all steps correctly? shebang, permissions?

Comment: The script is from docker-bench-security, its a github proyect, ye i tried with the chmod too, i have no idea whats going on

Comment: @Jose Check line 27 to 29 in your script where it check for required programs and echoes error if it is _not_ installed. That's the issue!

Answer (score 1):

@Jose - you are using docker-bench-security.sh script where in line 27, you have ss command(as pointed out by @daya). As ss is not supported in mac os, you can replace ss with netstat in your script and run the script as:
sh docker-bench-security.sh (if script doesn't use shebang)